# How can I deal with Winter Bash hats blocking page controls?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

As I do every now and then, I went to [Adrian Mole's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871073/adrian-mole) to see what they've been getting up to recently. Next to the "Profile" button there's usually an "Activity" button that I can click. At the moment however, it's entirely obscured by a hat.

[image]

Clicking this hat reveals that it's called "Milliner", and appears to be kind of like a meta-hat granted to users who have already earned a number of other hats as part of this year's Winter Bash festivities. This is nice to know, but I would still like to click the convenient "Activity" button and see other information.

I'm quite confident that this is part of an elaborate plan by Adrian Mole to hide all evidence of their wrongdoing from the public, and I fully intend on raising a custom flag about this. On the other hand, I must admit the far less entertaining possibility that I'm just doing something wrong with the UI here. Or that it's a bug, in which case how can I deal with it?

Comment: There was a similar question about a hat hiding the link, but it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358043/hats-can-block-page-controls

Comment: I have no recent activity. I have only hattivity.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah, I noticed :) The whole hat thing seems very popular. Looks like fun for sure.

Comment: But there are also some hat-ers as always.

Comment: As a workaround you could modify the link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871073/adrian-mole?tab=topactivity

Comment: Ahh.. I found those orange rounded buttons to be such a regression and displeasure to look at, that I spent time reverting them back to how they were before. It made me smile when Adrian Mole's hat was covering [**almost** all of **my** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCIdr.png). I just click the corner of **my** square button and get to all the other good stuff on their profile ;P

Comment: @Scratte This looks like an interesting approach to solve the problem. Could you write an answer that describes how you reverted the UI to show you the old version?

Comment: You can also hide your reputation by placing the "Flashlight" at the bottom-most position. https://i.imgur.com/LluklkS.png

Answer (score 21):

> *How can I see a milliner's activity?*

Just add `?tab=topactivity` to the URL in your browser's address bar, or replace "profile" with "topactivity" if that URL already ends with `?tab=profile`.

---

<sup>*(1)I posted this answer because I don't see why cigien should get all that Meta-Rep for using my profile, while I get zilch! There may even be badges and **hats** at stake!*</sup>

<sup>*(2)And I just edited yours, absolutely not just to see if it would give  any other*</sup>

Comment: If hats might be at stake, that alone justifies an answer. Have an upvote :)

Answer (score 9):

At least for me, the hat loads after the page --slow enough that I was able to successfully click the "Activity" button prior to the hat covering it over.

Comment: this will now be my go-to solution for this kind of problems: “open dev tools, set network connectivity to 2G, reload, etc.” :D

Comment: Yeah, this does work, thanks. This is a very interesting way to work around the bug.

Comment: I have to admit, I was hoping I'd get some kind of secret hat for answering this question, but that doesn't seem to have happened. :o

Answer (score 8):

You can also (temporarily) hide the hat:

```
$(".hat").toggle();
```

Comment: +1 for using jQuery

Answer (score 8):

What I do is temporarily disable the hat by clicking the "No hats for me, please" button, click "Activity", and then re-enable the hats by clicking "I Love Hats

[image: GIF explaining process]"