# What is the purpose of the hats that I'm receiving?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I've heard of Winter Bash before, but I have no idea what is the purpose of the hats that I'm receiving and what should I do with them. So I am just trying to understand here - what are the hats for, and why would I want to wear them?

Comment: For fun. That's it. Nothing more.

Comment: In 10years, this is the first time you notice it?

Comment: @Atiyar Usually you get a hat without even knowing that you did. Some hats are so easy to get. I'm surprised you didn't get one. For instance there's always a hat for visiting a question (unless you haven't visited a question in the past 10 years, which is highly unlikely).

Comment: @10Rep possible that OP hasn't visited the site _during Winter Bash_, or maybe quickly found and read questions once or twice during this period, and din't pay attention to the top-right icon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hats have no "real" functionality.

Winter Bash is intended to be a fun way to celebrate the year's end, encourage users to explore new ways to use SE they may have not tried yet, and participating in a joint effort to figure out the triggers for the secret hats.

If you're not interested, you could always opt-out of it by clicking the "no hats for me, please" button at the bottom of the Winter Bash menu.

Comment: Note the game as well.

Comment: Hat are you talking about? (just joking)

Comment: @10Rep, what game? Looks like I have a lot to "explore new ways to use SE" that I "may have not tried yet"  :)

Comment: @atiyar The Hat Dash game, which you can access by wearing a mask hat. More info on it in my question about it. :)

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Don't reveal it! jk many people found out anyways

Comment: Isn't a small part to encourage behaviour that lasts beyond the Winter Bash period?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The hats themselves will be removed when Winter Bash ends. One could presume, though, if users get into the habit of those behaviors, they would stick beyond Winter Bash.

Comment: TBH. you could argue the same logic exists for badges that can only be earned once - they promote behaviors that are considered positive, but after you get the badge, you have no "objective" reason to carry on with that positive behavior - unless it becomes a habit and/or you've internalized the value of this behavior

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is that they bring the community closer together, like:

> "Hey, you're wearing fruits on your head... so am I!"

And they give the site more pop and color...

Comment: That is, until [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403735/how-can-i-see-a-milliners-activity) happens

Comment: @Spectric What about it?