# Why do some developers take Winter Bash dead serious?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hatdash

There were plenty of questions regarding the hats on Meta Stack Overflow and some developers take Winter Bash dead serious and play hours. I'm just curious to know, do we have any prizes for the winners or any other benefits?

[image]

Note: I personally like this strategy of Stack Overflow, because of which thousands of new developers getting interacted with the site just to collect hats, but at the same time they are educating the society and that's what gamified education is.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the hats that I'm receiving?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403793/11682469)

Comment: 'Why do other people spent their free time different than me' ... yeah, who knows.

Comment: "some developers take winter bash dead serious and play hours" - four hours over the course of nearly a week isn't really a lot. I've put *thirteen* hours into *Hades* over that same time period.

Comment: Why not up the meta ante: why do some SO members take seriously that SO members take winter-bash hats seriously?

Comment: I mean, for the same reason some folks spend time playing Candy Crush. It's just a fun activity for them, despite not being really worth anything beyond that. Of course, unlike Candy Crush this is pure fun without an attempt to get money from the players.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on your definition of *dead serious*.

I call those devs *smart*. They did what we're good at: automating repetitive tasks.

Some might call that cheating.

I call it a friendly competition between "hackers" and [Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis).

See also: [Do you see a way to cheat at Hat Dash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358104/do-you-see-a-way-to-cheat-at-hat-dash)

Answer (score 9):

Why does anybody play any game? Some may enjoy the game itself, some may enjoy the accomplishment of topping the leader board, and some may just really like unicorns.

In other words - there's no prize associated with the Hat Dash. If you want to know why someone spends time on it, you'd have to ask them directly.